# Python convert daily column into a new dataframe with year as index week as column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, seaborn

I have a data frame with the date as an index and a parameter. I want to convert column data into a new data frame with year as row index and week number as column name and cells showing weekly mean value. I would then use this information to plot using `seaborn https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.relplot.html`.

**My data**:

```
df = 
              data
2019-01-03    10
2019-01-04    20
2019-05-21    30
2019-05-22    40
2020-10-15    50
2020-10-16    60
2021-04-04    70
2021-04-05    80
```

**My code**:

```
# convert the df into weekly averaged dataframe
wdf = df.groupby(df.index.dt.strftime('%Y-%W')).data.mean() 
wdf
2019-01  15
2019-26  35
2020-45  55
2021-20  75
```

**Expected answer**: Column name denotes the week number, index denotes the year. Cell denotes the sample's mean in that week.

```
       01    20    26    45
2019   15    NaN   35    NaN  # 15 is mean of 1st week (10,20) in above df
2020   NaN   NaN   NaN   55
2021   NaN   75    NaN   NaN
```

No idea on how to proceed further to get the expected answer from the above-obtained solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [pivot_table](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html) :

```
df['year'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(df['date']).year
df['week'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(df['date']).week

final_table = pd.pivot_table(data = df,index= 'year', columns = 'week',values = 'data', aggfunc = np.mean )
```

Comment: I have used this. `odf['week'] = df.index.dt.strftime('%W')` Another one giving some wrong data.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use two dimensions in the groupby, and then unstack to lay out the data as a grid:
`df.groupby([df.index.year,df.index.week])['data'].mean().unstack()`